# Using Head Voice

Tags: technique, voice

I have a very flat, bass voice. I can sing my bass notes brilliantly,  but the problem is when I go to higher notes. I heard that the head voice can solve this problem. But how do I use it in my voice?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you tagged your question [falsetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsetto) but you ask about [head voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_voice). Even though they can sound somewhat similar and they're often confused, they're different things. Either can be used to reach higher notes than you can reach with your chest voice but the resulting sound will be different.

It's near impossible to explain these techniques in writing. I understand you don't want singing lessons. Then the only other way is to google "how to access your head voice" and "how to access your falsetto" and watch some instructional videos.

But be warned; it's no substitute for actual lessons and can be damaging to your voice. I'd suggest you start with practicing falsetto (not head voice), it's harder (but very possible) to damage your voice with falsetto.

Comment: I edited and tagged it falsetto because there is no head voice tag.

Answer (score -1):

Answering your question will depend on whether you think that headvoice means staying connected to your full voice or simply a "non-breathy falsetto".

If you are referring to headvoice as meaning fullvoice but with it resonating in the head (still being connected to chest) then training it is not done through a single exercise but rather a complete PHASED TRAINING SYSTEM of developing:

1. The chest or call register separately and strongly as high as possible.  To do this you must learn how to breathe properly and learn how to engage the right muscles in the abdomen to create body an anchor for the sound - support.
2. Learning how to bridge into a non-breathy falsetto without a flip.
3. Learning how to then maintain compression by use of consonant sounds that act as crutches so that you can stay "connected" in your real voice.  When this happens, your larynx will tilt causing the folds to thin and allow you to sing higher.  If you want to read more about that, I made a huge article on it here:
   http://www.grow-the-voice.com/neutral-larynx/

This stuff isn't achieved by reading a post, watching a video or reading a forum.  It isn't a case of just "doing an exercise", it's about building up skills over time in a phased process.

I recently made an extremely detailed video on the difference between headvoice and falsetto, check it out here: